# setup remote repository - having trouble - tortoisegit

Tags: windows, git, amazon-ec2, tortoisegit

I have a local repository on my pc, and did this with Tortoisegit.

I also have an Amazon Web Services EC2 instance running Windows Server 2012, and have also installed Tortoisegit on there. I have opened port 9418(TCP), and created inbound firewall rules for it. I have a domain pointing to the server, and the server is accessible via HTTP (running apache) at my domain.

I have created a folder `c:\Repos` on the SERVER, and have set the HOME environment variable to point to this. Inside Repos I created a new folder named `ProjectX.git`, and then using the tortoise shell right click, created a BARE repository at the new folder.

I want to do an initial PUSH of my local repo, to the one on my server, by adding the server as a remote, but I'm not sure I have the url right.

```
 // also for clarification who is user?  
 // Do I use the windows username?
 git://user@hostname/ProjectX.git
```

Please refrain from 'elitist' answers such as 'use CLI idiot' or 'why dont u take the time to learn git properly instead of using gui shortcuts', which I see all over git questions online. GUI is there for a reason, enough said.

Comment: I always use [Bonobo Git Server](https://bonobogitserver.com/) to accomplish what you need. Never did it the way you're trying to do.

Comment: I always thought that there is no 'git server' per se, but every repo in itsself is a client/server that can communicate/sync

Comment: I do, however, use bare repositories for deploying and they have a url (http protocol, not git), but they're hosted on linux and ssh authentication is needed. Not sure how that would work on windows, though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decided that there just simply isn't enough good documentation out there to get the `git://` protocol setup on windows, and to permanently share repos, i opted for [SCM Manager](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjk9eyK9avJAhVIHxoKHa87CKoQFggpMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.scm-manager.org%2F&usg=AFQjCNHqonbXTSMAzmRgt-E4Vm-Zsxa3Mw&sig2=Y3enb3BriqBSXjJIebA6Wg).  Which happens to work great.   Very easy setup.